# Find and replace a pattern using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with multiple occurrences (more than 1000) of:

```
REF*SY*111111111, REF*SY*777777777, REF*SY*145485450...etc.
```

I need all the data be replaced with a standard output:

```
REF*SY*111111111,REF*SY*111111111, REF*SY*111111111 ....etc.
```

Can I do it with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: The answer is: yes, you can. Have you tried anything to solve your problem already? We won't give you solution, but we can help ypu if you will have any problem with your script

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  We are a question-answering community, not a scriptwriting community.  We're happy to help, but we're happy to _help_, not to just do your work for you, particularly without the sort of details we'd need to be able to assist you in this specific case.   What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?  Can you show us an example of actual input, and what the actual desired output would be?

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're asking. Is it replace all digits with "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man sed` is your friend here.  Making a few assumptions, I guess these should work for you:

```
sed -e 's/REF\*SY\*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/REF*SY*111111111/g'
perl -pe 's/REF\*SY\*[0-9]{9}REF*SY*111111111/g'
```

Comment: Thank you GarethHumphriesAcc. It Worked !!!!